# Is it possible to have a multi word enumeration case in swift?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have multi-word enumeration case e.g

```
enum Country: Int {
       case Pakistan=1,United Arab Emirates,United Kingdom
}
```

I tried:

```
enum Country: Int {
       case Pakistan=1,"United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom"
}
```

without luck :(

```
 <stdin>:3:46: error: expected identifier after comma in enum 'case' declaration
case Pakistan=1,"United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom"
^
<stdin>:3:46: error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
case Pakistan=1,"United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom"
^
;
<stdin>:3:46: error: expected declaration
case Pakistan=1,"United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom"
^
<stdin>:2:15: error: an enum with no cases cannot declare a raw type
enum Country: Int {
^
<stdin>:2:6: error: type 'Country' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'
enum Country: Int {
^
Swift.RawRepresentable:9:13: note: protocol requires nested type 'RawValue'
typealias RawValue
^
```

Answer (score 4):

NO, is the answer for your question.

Check the language reference of Swift:
[Enumeration Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID364)

> GRAMMAR OF AN ENUMERATION DECLARATION
>
> ...
>
> *enum-case-name* → [*identifier*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/identifier)
>
> ... ­

All enum case name needs to match [the syntax of *identifier*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/identifier), but space-separated words (even if you tried to enclose them in sort of quoting symbols) does not match.

If you can use `String` as RawValue of your enum, you can write something like this:

```
enum Country: String {
    case Pakistan, UnitedArabEmirates = "United Arab Emirates", UnitedKingdom = "United Kingdom"
}
```

But, as you see, this enum lacks `Int` information for each case, so may not fit for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use "space" in "case" declaration but you can use "under score". Then you can add property which replace "under score" to "space"

```
enum Country: Int {
    case Pakistan = 1
    case United_Arab_Emirates
    case United_Kingdom

    var stringValue: String {
        return String(self).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: " ")
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
    let country = Country.United_Arab_Emirates
    print(country.rawValue, ":", country.stringValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### No, it is not possible.

Instead, use PascalCase.

```
enum Country: Int {
   case Pakistan=1, UnitedArabEmirates, UnitedKingdom
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you could add reference to documentation , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You actually can as below and use those values:

```
enum SuctionFrequencyTime: Int {
    static let values = ["<½ Hr", "½ Hr", "Hourly", "2 Hourly", ">2 Hourly"]
    case lessThanHalfHour = 1, halfHour, hourly, twoHours, greaterThanTwoHours
}
```

If there are no spaces, you could use `CaseIterable` to conform to enum